# iterating through several TCL arrays

Tags: tcl

I would like to loop through one or more TCL arrays, printing a particular value, for instance.

Perhaps best described in code:

```
# Init
array unset one; array set one {param 1}
array unset two; array set two {param 2}

#Works fine
puts "one=$one(param)"
puts "two=$two(param)"

#Nope
foreach ar "one two" {puts ${$ar(param)}}

#Works, but makes a copy.
foreach tmp "one two" {
  array unset ar
  array set ar [array get $tmp]
  puts "$tmp=$ar(param)"
}
```

That "Works" case results in a copy (which I guess is no big deal), but it just doesn't doesn't look correct.  I'd prefer to have something more clean such as the "Nope" case (but which works :).

Comment: I consider all the answers provided by donal-fellows, glenn-jackman, and slebetman to be accurate and properly answer the intent of what I am trying to do.  I selected @slebetman because it was closest to answer my specific question: How do I write the "Nope" case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution, if you **really** want the Nope case to work, is to remember that `$x` is just a shorthand for `[set x]` and `set`, being a proper command, plays better with the rest of tcl syntax than `$` which is merely syntax.

So, reformulating your double `$$` into `set` gives us this working code:

```
foreach ar "one two" {puts [set [set ar](param)]}
```

The first round of substitution, `[set ar]` merely replaces `ar` with the value "one" or "two". The advantage of `set` over `$` in this situation is that it gives us, the programmer, the control of where to stop the substitution. We can either do `[set ar(param)]` which is the same as `$ar(param)` or we can stop earlier: `[set ar](param)` which is what we want in this case.

Comment: Actually, the second `set` is not necessary. You can write it like `foreach ar "one two" {puts "$ar=[set ${ar}(param)]"}`

Comment: `$foo` is not a shorthand for `set foo`. See `trace`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: The saying "$foo is a shorthand for [set foo]" is a traditional one used to explain tcl's substitution rules. Also, for the purposes of `trace` both `$foo` and `set foo` trigger variable traces (though obviously only `set foo` would trigger command trace on `set`)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that that's ugly. The best way to do this sort of thing is with a *local variable alias*. You make those with `upvar 0`.

```
foreach arrayName {one two} {
    upvar 0 $arrayName ar
    puts "$arrayName=$ar(param)"
}
```

You're *advised* that this is best done within a procedure, because you can't really undo the variable aliasing. That can make the use of `upvar` more conventional.

```
proc printEntry {entry args} {
    foreach arrayName $args {
        # Use [upvar 1] because we want the caller's name
        upvar 1 $arrayName ar
        puts "$arrayName=$ar($entry)"
    }
}
printEntry param one two
```

(If you're using `upvar`, always use the level parameter — `0` and `1` above — to avoid some ugly mis-parsing problems.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could alter your data structure:

```
# Init
array set a {
    "one,param" 1
    "two,param" 2
}

puts "one=$a(one,param)"
puts "two=$a(two,param)"

foreach key {one two} {puts $a($key,param)}
```